# QNetworkManager uploading file to FTP crash

Tags: qt, ftp, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to upload a simple test text file to a FTP server. In order to achieve this I am using [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), since [QFtp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html) has been deprecated in Qt 5.1.

I created a test.txt file in the programs directory and using [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfile.html) I am opening it as `QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text`.

The problem is when I set the connection and tell the [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to upload a file the program crashes ("FTPConnectionTest does not respond"). It happens both when I am trying to use an external FTP server or a local one created with `FileZilla`.

I connected all signals emitted by the reply (functions: `uploadFinish`, `uploadProgress`, `uploadError`) however no feedback is beeing captured.

Question: Is this problem lying on the side of FTP server or am I doing something wrong in my code?
Code snipped below:

Main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <ftp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Ftp ftp;
    return a.exec();
}
```

ftp.cpp

```
#include "ftp.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QFile>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDebug>

Ftp::Ftp()
{   
    QFile file("test.txt");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)) {
        url = QUrl("ftp://127.0.0.1/test.txt");
        url.setUserName("user");
        url.setPassword("password");

        qDebug() << "URL set" << url;

        QNetworkAccessManager* nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
        qDebug() << "nam set";
        QNetworkReply *rep = nam->put(QNetworkRequest(url), &file);
        qDebug() << "after rep";

        connect(rep, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(uploadFinish()));
        connect(rep, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(uploadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
        connect(rep, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    }
    else qDebug() << "failed to open";
}

void Ftp::uploadFinish()
{
    qDebug() << "finished uploading file";
}

void Ftp::uploadProgress(qint64 a, qint64 b)
{
    qDebug() << a << "/" << b;
}

void Ftp::uploadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError state)
{
    qDebug() << "State" << state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `QNetworkAccessManager::put` documentation:

> *data* must be opened for reading when this function is called and must remain valid until the finished() signal is emitted for this reply.

Your `file` object falls out of scope when the constructor finishes execution, so `QNetworkAccessManager` probably tries to read from object that is already deleted. You need to make `file` a class member variable or create it using `QFile* file = new QFile()`.

Comment: Yeah that was the case, I figured it out myself just before I read your answer. Thank you.